# .NET assemblies loading

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, assemblies

I want to make the WPF application with loading my app logic assemblies behind the splash screen, like a NetBeans IDE with progress bar. I understand that my application is small and there is no sence in it, but i want do such thing if it can be done in .NET

Comment: Why do you want to make your application annoying to your users? If it takes your application 30 seconds to load, then a splash screen is appropriate. But if your application can start instantly, when delay it arbitrarily? This is very bad UX. That said, have you tried Googling?

Comment: This problem is mostly educational for me than functionality needed. Besides i think i solve it and i got a splash screen with progress bar. So i can see my app logic assemblies loading into the application on the startup. Yes, it takes less than half of second. Before yesterday i even could not imagine how to do it. And i think i keep my splash screen in my app because i think it make my UX better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the assemblies loading progress information first we determine which of the assemblies were not being loaded to the moment. So we need to know the full list of assemblies that would be loaded to the AppDomain (from referenced assemblies) and compare them to already loaded assemblies.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
```

Than we can force loading missed assemblies and display progress information.

```
foreach (AssemblyName assembly in assembliesToLoad)
{
    ShowAssemblyLoadingInformation(assembly);

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(assembly);

    ReportProgress();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656886.aspx

This really allows the .NET runtime to show a static splash screen while loading your assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

Yes i agree with "fsimonazzi" idea. But if you think you need to do a lot of long processes in sync with the front splash screen loading to show the process progress and more cool stuffs you can do that by using the following article as reference :[Splash Screen in WPF using custom application start-up class](http://www.jsinh.in/2012/04/how-to-create-animated-splash-screen-using-custom-application-startup-class-in-wpf/)